# operator is undefined for args

Tags: java

I keep getting the error message `the operator type is undefined for the args` when I use any boolean operators in java. Do I have to import a boolean class or something?

```
import java.util.Scanner; //imports Scanner class 

public class LeapYear {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        //create Scanner object
        Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);

        //declare variables
        int year;

        //get input
        System.out.println("Enter year: ");
        year = input.nextInt();

        //create if statement   
            if ((year/4) && !(year/100)){
                System.out.println("Leap Year");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Not a Leap Year");
            }
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you think this `!(year/100)` does?

Comment: This won't work for all cases - it's a hack rather than a solution. Look at the `Calendar` api; specifically [`GregorianCalendar.isLeapYear()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#isLeapYear(int))

Comment: NB your leap-year test is incorrect. If (year % 400 == 0) it is a leap year. 2000 was an example.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike C/C++, you cannot treat `int` values as `booleans`.  You must explicitly compare them to zero to create the `boolean` result.  Additionally, for leap year calculations, you want to compare the *remainder* when dividing, so us `%` instead of `/`:

```
if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) {
```

Don't forget about years divisible by 400, which are leap years.  I'll leave that change to you.

Comment: thanks a million, hadn't forgotten about the 400 just wanted to get this sorted first! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
(year/4) && !(year/100)
```

Neither of these integer operations equate to booleans. You might want to try something like:

```
if(year%4 == 0)
```

or something along those lines. I know the leap-year logic isn't perfect there, but the point is you need to be making some sort of comparison (==).

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of division "/" use mode "%".

```
if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) {
```